# How to differentiate between logout and session expired?

Tags: java, jsp, session, session-timeout

Case 1: Log out : Once we log out, if one tries to access previous, it must automatically redirect to login.jsp

Case 2: Session expired : If session expires when user is still logged in, it must try to automatically redirect to sessionExpired.jsp when previous page is accessed.

How to differentiate ? I am currently invalidating session when logging out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On login, set a cookie with a long expiry (> 24 hours). Remove this cookie at logout time by setting the maxage to 0.

You can have check for any non-logged in user (i.e. invalid session id). 
If the cookie does not exist, redirect him to login.jsp

If the cookie exists, it means his session expired so redirect him to session-expired.jsp

Comment: Thanks. I am going to implement this.

Comment: if i try to recreate a cookie using firefox webdeveloper plugin , the code may fail.

Answer (score 8):

You can test expired sessions by checking if [`HttpServletRequest#getRequestedSessionId()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestedSessionId%28%29) doesn't return `null` (which means that the client has sent a session cookie and thus assumes that the session is still valid) and [`HttpServletRequest#isRequestedSessionIdValid()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#isRequestedSessionIdValid%28%29) returns `false` (which means that the session has been expired at the server side).

In a nut:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

    if (request.getRequestedSessionId() != null && !request.isRequestedSessionIdValid()) {
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/sessionexpired.jsp");
    } else if (session == null || session.getAttribute("user") == null) {
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/login.jsp");
    } else {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

No need to hassle with extra cookies. Map this `Filter` on an `url-pattern` covering the protected pages (and thus excluding the sessionexpired and login pages!).

Don't forget to disable page caching by the browser on the protected pages, otherwise the webbrowser will load them from the cache when you're going back in the browser history, instead of sending a new request to the server. You can achieve this by doing the following in the same filter, *before* `Chain#doFilter()` call.

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
```

Comment: If i am redirecting from one page to another let say login type page( select google login or default login) to login page, both happens before logging in, does above code redirect to session expired page ??

Comment: Understood the above answer but what will happen if we implement http basic authentication mechanism ..before hitting to any url or servlet on server side it will throw 401 to the client..how to handle in this case?

Comment: Just replace by FORM authentication if you want more fine grained control.

Comment: i can't replace http basic authentication mechanism  with  FORM authentication , without this i want to implement

Answer (score 1):

If it were me I would clear the session on log out and create a bool in it called HasLoggedOut then set this to true. Then if this bool exists in session you know they logged out, if it doesn't then the session has either timed out or the user never logged in at all.

As you still cant differentiate between timed out and not logged in I normally make the decision that if they request an authenticated page I will just send them to session timeout page which also doubles as a login page that says something like

"Oops, we don't know who you are, either your session has timed out or you have not yet logged in please login below"

This then caters for both scenarios

Comment: Thanks. Its a good idea, however displaying you are new user or your session is timed out doesn't look good.