# Java EE + GlassFish: Force user to logout if he/she log in somewhere else

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I hope my question on the title make sense, if not, let say: machine A, via the web browser I log in as `admin`, I go to machine B, and log in as `admin`, the web browser in machine A should force a logout on user `admin`. I gave this some thought, and I think it will be ugly if I try to manual implement this. I have a feeling that this can be done in Glassfish.

I use Java EE 6 + Glassfish v3.0.1. Authentication and authorization are implemented via jdbcRealm set up in Glassfish

Comment: Do you control both machines? If not, are the machines both in the same domain, and is B issuing cookies for the shared domain rather than itself? If the answer to both questions is no, then this can't be done.

Comment: @Tom: I think he actually meant "client machine", not "server machine" here. @Harry: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372311/jsf-how-to-invalidate-an-user-session-when-he-logs-twice-with-the-same-credentia

Comment: @BalusC: Aaah, yes, my misunderstanding, i see.

Comment: Thank you so much BalusC and sorry for the confusion Tom. +1

Comment: @BalusC: Thanks, I figure it out. Just out of curiosity, if I want to create a notification saying that you have been log out because you log in somewhere else, how would I come about to accomplish that?

Comment: You'd like to check if the user has requested a session ID which is after all invalid. See my answer on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306228/how-to-differentiate-between-logout-and-session-expired).

Answer (score 5):

- create and map (using `<listener>..</listener>` in web.xml) a `HttpSessionListener`
- on `sessionCreated(..)` store a reference to the session in the `ServletContext`, in a `Map<String, Session>`
- when the user logs-in, get the `Map` from the `ServletContext` and see if any session there has the same user / userId as a session attribute.
- if there is, `session.invalidate()` it.
- if you want to use this in a cluster, you can either use a database to store the information so that it is accessible from everywhere, or use a distributed cache (JBoss Cache, Ehcache)

Comment: Maybe a Map<String, HttpSession> rather than a set, to allow easy lookups by userid rather than having to iterate.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen, if the solution has to involve Java, the map must be shared across all JVMs (so possibly Terracotta or Coherence might help). But such a solution can be considered "heavy" if an object caching solution is used for only one feature. It might in fact, turn out to be easier to store the list in a database, and lazily-expire sessions.

Comment: Can you give me some sample codes? The above explanation even though are extremely good, but I am a bit new to this business, so lots of them dont even make much sense to me. Thank you and sorry for the trouble

Comment: @Harry: basically, you need to replace `Map<String, Session>` (as per Bozho's example) by a (shared) database table and fire SQL queries instead of `Map#get()`, `Map#remove()` and so on.

Comment: Or a distributed cache. I added these options to the answer