# Validate JSESSIONID for each request

Tags: jsf, spring-security

I'm using Spring Security in my web application.

I received a vulnerability check report stating that using a wrong JSESSIONID in "Cookie" header will always redirect to the login page. However, it should redirect to an error page.

I've tried to use `<session-management invalid-session-url="/denied.xhtml" />` to solve this issue but it didn't work for me.

How do I force redirection to error page when JSESSIONID is wrong or randomly generated by an external party?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you aware that expired sessions would also be matched this way?

Comment: Yes, I need to redirect the user in both cases to an invalid-session page.

Comment: OK. Do you already know how exactly that Spring approach failed? Was you firing a JSF ajax request? Have you observed the HTTP traffic? I don't do Spring, so I can't answer that part (and its documentation also seems to suggest that your attempt should work), but I can answer the plain vanilla servlet filter approach. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306228/how-to-differentiate-between-logout-and-session-expired/3308398#3308398 This is only not JSF ajax aware yet (but I can answer that as well, if needed).

Comment: I tried to submit a request to the login page (public page) with a Cookie JSESSIONID that I made up and I received login page response where I expected to be redirected to the error page

Comment: Did you rebuild/redeploy/restart after the setting change?

Comment: Sure I did. The correct redirection only worked when logging out.